# Expected usage of move constructor not happening

Tags: c++, c++11

This is my class and my program:

```
class A {
    public:
        int x;
        int* v;
        A() : x(5), v(new int[5]) {cout<<"default ctor. "; for (int i=0; i<x; i++) v[i]=rand()%10;}
        A(const A& a) : x(a.x), v(new int[x]) {cout<<"copy ctor. "; for (int i=0; i<x; i++) v[i]=a.v[i]; }
        A(A&& a) : x(a.x), v(a.v) {cout<<"move ctor. ";a.x=0;a.v=0;}
        A& f() {return *this;}
        A g() {return *this;}
};

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    cout<<"A a --> ";A a;cout<<endl;
    cout<<"A b(A()) --> ";A b(A());cout<<endl;
    cout<<"A c(a.f()) --> ";A c(a.f());cout<<endl;
    cout<<"A d(a.g()) --> ";A d(a.g());cout<<endl;
    cout<<"A e(A().g()) --> ";A e(A().g());cout<<endl;
}
```

I would expect the objects `b`, `d` and `e` to use the move constructor, however the output I get is:

> A a --> default ctor.
>
> A b(A()) -->
>
> A c(a.f()) --> copy ctor.
>
> A d(a.g()) --> copy ctor.
>
> A e(A().g()) --> default ctor. copy ctor.

If in all three cases r-values are the arguments of the constructors, why isn't the move constructor being used?

Obviously I am compiling with the `-std=c++11` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `b`, you've hit the "[most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)." `b` is a function declaration, not an object.

Take the expression

```
A b(A());
```

Let's do some name changes and semantic-preserving transformations:

```
int foo(int (*p)());
```

Now, I think it's pretty clear that `foo` is a function (returns `int` and takes pointer to `int()` function as parameter). Now substitute back `A` for `int`, `b` for `foo` and remember functions get implicitly converted to pointer-to-function. You'll see it's the same thing.

To get around this, you can use brace initialisation (thanks to @MikeSeymour for pointing that out):

```
A b{A()};
```

With `d`, I think you're the "victim" of [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). The "copy ctor" output is probably from initialising the return value with `*this`; the move from the return value to `d` is completely elided.

With `e`, it's the same story as `d`.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning how to avoid the vexing parse: `A b{A()};` or `A b((A()));`

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks, I never remember that, as I'm stuck with VS2010 and thus no brace-init :-(

Comment: it would have never occured to me that I was declaring a function. Also, I compiled with the `-fno-elide-constructors` option and now I can see the move constructors are indeed being used. It's hard to get to know how the language works when the compiler does *bad* things (meaning, unexpected behaviour) with **good** purpose.

Comment: @dabadaba If you didn't have `-fno-elide-constructors` and you really wanted to know for sure which initializations use the move constructor, you could simply declare it as deleted: `A(A&&) = delete;`. Then instead of copy/move elision messing with you, you'd get a convenient error message.